# Inheritance of database tables in VS

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, entity-framework, database-design

I want to create Table-Per-Type database table inheritance.

Simply base table `RowElement` will have 2 children tables. First child table `Lyrics` will inherit all parents `RowElement`'s columns and will just add one more column. Second child table `ChordUse` will only many-to-one relationship to table `Chord`.

This is how my database schema looks like:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ae4d8bd348.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ae4d8bd348.jpg)

The problem is that when I let the VS create E/R diagram for me it creates this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/774b194451.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/774b194451.jpg)

So it creates an 1-to-1-0 entity relationship instead of inheritance. I can't get VS to create inheritance relationship mapped correctly to database. Please help me.

After generating E/R diagram from my database I would like to have something like:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e532f09b8a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e532f09b8a.jpg)

Where `RowElement` is abstract class. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EF designer (for good reasons, IMHO -- inheritance is overused in OR models) will never infer inheritance. You need to set it up yourself. You are asking for "table per type" inheritance. Follow the [walkthrough with the demo model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716702.aspx). When you've got that working, you'll be ready to do it with your real model.

Comment: I have already done it without the tutorial. I took me 2 more days to figure it out as the designer is not really intuitive. Anyway, nobody on this site seemed to care to explain me those 3-4 easy steps how to do it.